# C passing string to function issue

Tags: c

I'm having an issue passing a char* to a function in C.

I have a method `dns_magic`, where one of the parameters is a `char *addr`. In addition, I have a `char temp[20]`, which contains a string (typically something like `irc.rizon.net`). Right before I call `dns_magic(temp)`, I do a `printf("Temp: %s", temp)` and it prints as expected. In the first line of `dns_magic`, I call `printf("Addr: %s", addr)`, and it prints nothing (as if the string is null).

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
printf("Temp: %s", temp);
res = dns_magic(temp, conf->port, &hints);
```

and

```
struct addrinfo *dns_magic(char *addr, int port_i, struct addrinfo hints)
{
    printf("Addr: %s", addr);
```

Could someone help tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried changing dns_magic to take a char[20] and disabling compiler optimization, but neither seems to have fixed the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on compiler warnings and get rid of them.

I'd suggest that your 3rd parameter is messing things up.  You declare a whole struct but pass in a pointer to one.  The stack is messed up and the function can't properly find the parameters passed.

You should make the last parameter a `struct addrinfo *hints` with appropriate `const` modifiers.

Comment: I already had all compiler warnings (-Wall -Wextra and -pedantic) on, but it turns out I had forgotten to include the header in the corresponding source file - this led to me not noticing that my header file had a different declaration, which destroyed my stack and caused the issue. Although this comment wasn't 100% accurate (turned out it was hard to be with given info), it's very close so I'll mark it accepted anyway.